# Read and split multiple lines into individual strings

Tags: java

I hope you are well.
Currently I'm struggling with a school project in Java. We have to create "a streaming/entertainment service" where a host is able to "host a show", with this not being actually implemented. I've made it so that the host of the "show" can fill in all needed informations about the show and writes this to a file. In order to show the "viewers" what shows is about to come, I need to read this from the same file and assemble all the lines as one String. 
My data set is currently as

```
Title
Genre
Entertainment type
Date and time
Length of show
Price of show (if any)
"-"
```

I've made the "-" in the end of each "show" to be able to split on this, but I can't seem to have any luck with this.
A snippet of a data set would be:

```
Show #1
Stream
Review
2020-10-10T10:00
90
0.0
-
Show#2
Stream
Review
2020-10-10T10:00
90
0.0
```

What I thought to do:

```
public class ShowHandler{
private String[] shows;
public void readShows(){
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Shows.txt"));
String line;
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
//split the read lines when the "-" occurs
//add these to each place in an array/list
    }
  }
}
```

The two comments in the while loop is what I thought would do the trick, but somehow I haven't been able to do this. Any clever and experienced minds who can help me?

Best regards.

Comment: How about a temporary String variable inside the while loop, where you add the next line to and only when the line equals "-" you put that temporary variable into your shows array and empty it?

Comment: Your dates have dashes in them.  You need another character or characters besides a single dash to terminate the block of Strings.  Maybe 3 dashes "---"?  A better approach would be to create a Show class with the six variables and keep a List of Show instances.

Comment: You are absolutely right, @GilbertLeBlanc. I didn't even think about the dash in the date. I solved it with a Show class. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> split the read lines when the "-" occurs

Do not split lines on `-` as each record also has a date field which has `-`. You can use an instance of `List<List<String>>` to store each record where each record can be an instance of `List<String>`.

Read each line and put into a `List<String>` and as soon as a `-` occurs, copy it to the instance of `List<List<String>>` and reset `List<String>` to gather the lines for the next record.

**Demo:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Test
        readShows().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    static List<List<String>> readShows() throws IOException {
        List<List<String>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Shows.txt"));
        String line;
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            // Transfer the data from `list` to `listOfLists` and create a new list as soon
            // as `-` occurs
            if (line.equals("-")) {
                listOfLists.add(list);
                list = new ArrayList<>();
            } else {
                list.add(line);
            }
        }
        // Add the last record
        listOfLists.add(list);

        bufferedReader.close();
        return listOfLists;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[Show #1, Stream, Review, 2020-10-10T10:00, 90, 0.0]
[Show#2, Stream, Review, 2020-10-10T10:00, 90, 0.0]
```

Comment: Why use `List<ArrayList<String>>` instead of `List<List<String>>`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I used the solution @GilbertLeBlanc provided. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @rasm937k -  You are most welcome. Wish you success!